# Appending items to masonry with Meteor's

Tags: meteor, jquery-masonry

I use a Masonry-style layout.

```
<div id="grid">
    {{#each items}}
        {{> item}}  <!-- <div class="to-grid"> ... </div> -->
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

When the layout is rendered on the first time, with the number of items limited to X, the masonry works well.

```
Template.masonryitems.rendered = function() {
    $('#grid').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $('#grid').masonry({
          itemSelector : '.to-grid'
        });            
    });
}
```

The number of items is reactively updated when user click on 'load more' button (as it is described here https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/).

With the enabled masonry effects the new loaded items replace the old ones - the number of items displayed on the page don't change.

I guess that new-loaded items need to be appended into masonry, but how to detect/query them?

```
$('#grid').masonry()
    .append( newElements ) //this shall be done automatically thanks to reactive subscription
    .masonry('appended', newElements);
```